# why is 'this' suddenly out of scope for me?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

I think I'm going crazy. I have 2 nearly identical pieces of code and in 1 of them the keyword this references the correct scope while in the other it doesn't. I've been staring at it for 3 hours and need other eyes.

The first function is this:

```
 renderField({input, options, label, name, multi}){
        let list = options.map(category=>{
            return {value:category.name, label:category.name}
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <label>{label}</label>
                <Select
                    value={this.state.selected}
                    multi={multi}
                    name={name}
                    className="basic-multi-select"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    options={list}
                    onChange={(e)=>{
                        this.setState({selected:e});
                        input.onChange(e);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

the this I'm referring to is the line `this.setState({selected:e});`. This code works. the 'this' is called in the correct scope. I needed to refactor the code so I wrote another function in a higher level component and bound it to that class. I then proceeded to chane the above to the following:

```
 renderField({defaultValue, input, options, label, name, multi, initialValues}){
        let list = options.map(category=>{
            return {value:category.name, label:category.name}
        });
        return(
            <div>
                <label>{label}</label>
                <Select
                    value={this.props.selected}
                    multi={multi}
                    name={name}
                    className="basic-multi-select"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    options={list}
                    onChange={(e)=>{
                            this.props.changeState(this.props.state_handler, e);
                            input.onChange(e);
                        }
                    }
                />
            </div>
        )

    }
```

suddenly this is no longer in scope and is now pointing at the `e` argument that I'm passing in. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use your JavaScript debugger and set a breakpoint on the line with the wrong `this` value, then look at the call-stack to see where `this` is being changed (presumably your `onChange` handler isn't being called with `.bind`).

Comment: use `that` and set it to `this` in `renderField`. In event handler, this should be the event target itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event handler, `this` means the event target.

So you should set a variable to remember the `this` in `renderField`.

Here's an example with comment.

```
renderField({defaultValue, input, options, label, name, multi, initialValues}){
    let list = options.map(category=>{
        return {value:category.name, label:category.name}
    });
    // set that to current this
    let that = this;
    return(
        <div>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <Select
                value={this.props.selected}
                multi={multi}
                name={name}
                className="basic-multi-select"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                options={list}
                onChange={(e)=>{
                        // this.props.changeState(this.props.state_handler, e);
                        // use that instead
                        that.props.changeState(that.props.state_handler, e);
                        input.onChange(e);
                    }
                }
            />
        </div>
    )

}
```